# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'adoptedStyleSheets' property on 'ShadowRoot': Can't adopt non-constructed stylesheets

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

Hot to use style element in shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets?

```html
<style id=style>
  h1 { color: red }
</style>
<script>
  customElements.define('test-elem', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor () {
      super()
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' })
      shadow.adoptedStyleSheets = [style.sheet]
      shadow.append(template.content.cloneNode(true))
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets
- You must create a Constructable Sheet with `new CSSStyleSheet()`
- You can only attach content on an `'open'` shadowRoot

```html
<style id="sourcestyle">
  h1 {
    color: green
  }
</style>

<my-element></my-element>

<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
      sheet.replace(document.getElementById("sourcestyle").innerHTML);

      super() // returns this/element scope
        .attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }) // both sets and returns this.shadowRoot
        .innerHTML = `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`;

      this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
    }
  })
</script>
```

Maybe better to construct that ***re-usable*** stylesheet outside your component,
and without creating a global `<style>`

```js
  const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
  sheet.replace(`h1{color:green}`);
```

#### Without Constructable StyleSheet

(Constructable CSS doesn't work in all Browsers yet)

otherwise you might as well *move* the `<style>` with:
(or cloneNode it when you want to re-use it)

```js
  this.shadowRoot.append(document.getElementById("sourcestyle"));
```

Since it is a global sheet, you may want to disable it for the main DOM

```
  <style id="sourcestyle" onload="this.disabled=true">
    h1 {
      color: green
    }
  </style>
```

and then undo the disabled once it is in a shadowDOM:

```js
  this.shadowRoot.getElementById("sourcestyle").disabled=false;
```

Comment: "You can only attach content on an 'open' shadowRoot" - nope, it works on 'closed' too